# How to convert class based detail view in function based view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am a learner I am learning django by doing an accounting application using django.

I was wondering how to convert a critical class based detail view to function based view

This is my code which I want to convert:

```
class ledger1DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'ledger1_details'
    model = ledger1
    template_name = 'accounting_double_entry/ledger1_details.html'

    def get_object(self):
        pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
        pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
        get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
        ledger = get_object_or_404(ledger1, pk=pk2)
        return ledger

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ledger1DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['journal_list']    = journal.objects.all()
        context['company_list']    = company.objects.all()
        journal_details            = get_object_or_404(journal, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['Debitcount']      = journal_details.debitsum()
        context['company_list']    = journal_details.creditsum()
        company_details            = get_object_or_404(company, pk=self.kwargs['pk1'])
        context['company_details'] = company_details
    return context
```

This is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^company/(?P<pk1>\d+)/ledgerdetail/(?P<pk2>\d+)/$',views.ledger1DetailView.as_view(),name='ledgerdetail'),
```

So you can understand what pk1 and pk2 is...And pk is the id for the journal objects...I want to pass some function which I have performed in the journal model in ledger1detailview...

If anyone know how to do it...plz help

Thank you

Comment: I find this rather weird, normally the tendency is to move th CBVs since these are more *declarative*.

Comment: No,I dont want to do this in my project..I just want to know if there is a way of doing it...@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Well you can look at the "reduced" (in the sense that it only shows overrides) implementation of a `DetailView`, and make all the logic explicit (and removing unnecessary parts): https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to write the function signature. Since it's a function not a class, the recommended name changes to `ledger1_detail_view`. The `login_required` decorator does the same job as `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Then, you need to fetch the object. This is similar to the code in `get_object`. Note that you don't have `self.kwargs` any more, you have `pk1` and `pk2` from the function signature.

Then you need to build up the context dictionary. This will be similar to your `get_context_data` method.

Finally you can use the `render` shortcut to render the template.

Putting it together, the structure of your view will be:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def ledger1_detail_view(request, pk1, pk2):

    get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
    ledger = get_object_or_404(ledger1, pk=pk2)

    context = {}
    context['ledger1_details'] = ledger
    # Add other items to the context
    ...

    return render(request, 'accounting_double_entry/ledger1_details.html', context)
```

Remember to change your url pattern to use the new view:

```
url(r'^company/(?P<pk1>\d+)/ledgerdetail/(?P<pk2>\d+)/$', views. ledger1_detail_view, name='ledgerdetail'),
```

Comment: What do I have to do for the pk that I use for the journal objects??

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the class based view you can use `self.kwargs['pk1']` and `self.kwargs['pk2']`. In the function based view use `pk1` and `pk2` instead. Your URL doesn't include `pk`, so you can't use `pk` in the class based view or function based view.

Comment: So,Is there is any other way to run the function of journal model in ledger1 detail view...Without including the pk to urls???

Comment: You can store it in `COOKIES`, `session`, a hidden field in a form (for example to obtain it again in `POST`), or a `GET` parameter, but I would not advise any of these, since it is rather "chaotic", and for some of the above methods, it can also be a challenge to "get rid of" the pk in a next step.